# Play/Slick Database only updates after recompile

Tags: playframework, slick

I am getting in trouble with Slick and Play framework. Been doing some code and everything works just fine but suddenly for one specific table...

I am able to make changes to the table but I can see those changes in my application only after re-comiling. Which you can understand is not very practical :D

I end up supposing there is a caching problem somewhere but can not find the source.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Slick doesn't do any caching.

Comment: But play! does. I supposed it comes from here. Without caching I do not know how to explain the behaviour

Comment: I don't think Play will cache that unless you explicitly ask for it. Can you show that code?